# Matching regular characters using scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I want to validate user input, making sure they enter only regular characters (combination of 0-9, A-Z, and a-z).

This is what I have, but its matching strings like "adsifj%a%%dosif". Which I do not want. It wont match if those invalid characters were at the beginning. How can I fix this?

```
int main(){
char name[128];

int match = scanf(" %[0-9a-zA-Z^\n]", name); 
printf("%d", match);    

if (match == 1){
    printf("Matched");
}else{
    printf("Invalid");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your variable match should first of all be an array of characters (aka a string).

Comment: The `^` in the scanset is suspicious.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't have true regex support, so it won't do what you want. The alternative is to read the string, and then check the string with `strspn`.

Comment: Yes 'name' is an arrray of characters.

Comment: @Mat Ok so I'm guessing match is the value that match is supposed to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
int match = scanf(" %[0-9a-zA-Z^\n]", name);
```

you should write:

```
char line[80], name[80];
char toomuch;

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL && sscanf(line, " %79[0-9A-Za-z] %c", name, &toomuch) == 1) {
    printf("name=(%s)\n", name);
}
```

First, read a complete line using `fgets`. Then, split that line into tokens using `sscanf`. The first token is the regular name, and the second token is the next character after the name that is not whitespace.

The input is valid if the line consists of any whitespace, followed by a regular word, followed by any whitespace, and then ends. There must not be any other characters left. This is why I am reading 2 tokens (name and toomuch) but only expecting 1 to be successfully read (the `== 1`).

Splitting the work between `fgets` and `sscanf` is necessary. If they were combined into `scanf(" %80[0-9A-Za-z] %c", name, &toomuch)`, the `%c` would need to read a second line sometimes, especially when you enter a correct regular name.

Note the `%79` in the argument to `sscanf`. It is necessary to prevent a buffer overflow.

Comment: `First, read a complete line using fgets.`What's wrong with scanf?

Comment: @Michi I've explained that in the third paragraph.

Comment: My  point was, that here on SO I see that `scanf` is a terrible choice and instead of showing how to be proper used, they just show you a "Better Alternative". `scanf` is not wrong, it is all most always used WRONG

Comment: @Michi But if everybody that attempts to use `scanf` uses it incorrectly, doesn't that indicated that `scanf` itself is poorly designed. A well designed function is one that is easy to understand and easy to use correctly. `scanf` has way too many quirks to be called a well designed function.

Comment: @user3386109 This is the funny part of using/knowing `C` Language. Any way saying that `fgets` is better then `scanf` is like trying to compare `fgets` with `getline`. `C` language is not for everyone :).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like this:

**edit**: I edited the code to match the size of your name array.

```
char name[128];
int match = scanf("%127[0-9A-Za-z]", name);
if (match == 1) {
  printf("Success.%s.\n", name);
} else {  
  puts("There exist non-matching characters");
  // To read all non matching characters
  fgetc(stdin); 
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't catch special characters at the end of the string.